# Should I rescale losses before combining them for multitask learning?

Tags: neural-network, machine-learning-model, loss-function, multiclass-classification, multitask-learning

I have a multitask network taking one input and trying to achieve two tasks (with several shared layers, and then separate layers).

One task is multiclass classification using the CrossEntropy loss, the other is sequence recognition using the CTC loss.

I want to use a combination of the two losses as criterion, something like *Loss = λCE + (1-λ)CTC*. The thing is that my *CE* loss starts around 2 while the *CTC* loss is in the 400s.

Should I rescale the losses at each epoch with a *Max(L₁)/L₁* factor, where *Max(L₁)* is the maximal loss at epoch 1 and *L₁* is each “sub-loss” at epoch 1. That is we scale the loss so that at the first epoch they have the same magnitude and then we keep scaling using those factors.

Is there a better approach? How do I ensure that my two losses have the same influence on the backpropagation with respect to λ?

Comment: Hi @silverduck. Can you upvote my answer too, trying to build some reputation 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://medium.com/huggingface/how-to-build-a-state-of-the-art-conversational-ai-with-transfer-learning-2d818ac26313).

Under the heading **Multi-tasks losses** they have mentioned how they average losses from two different tasks. They do a weighted average depending on their use case.